# Create desktop alias for Terminal starting in specific directory

Tags: macos

How can I create a desktop alias/icon for Terminal starting in a specific directory (without changing the Terminal global default starting directory)?

I'm coming from Windows where this is possible by right clicking a desktop shortcut for cmd and specifying the starting directory in the properties.

I've looked everywhere and found a lot of explanations of how to make aliases within terminal itself (in the .profile), but this is not what we're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply create a shell-script with the command `cd ~/specific/directory` and make it executable so that you can click-execute it right from the desktop.
It will then open a new Terminal window and go into `~/specific/directory`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
touch ~/Documents/myfinder.sh
chmod +x ~/Documents/myfinder.sh
echo 'open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app /System/Library/CoreServices/' > ~/Documents/myfinder.sh
ln -s ~/Documents/myfinder.sh ~/Desktop/
```

This will create a script in your Documents folder and a link to it on your desktop.  Change the argument to Terminal to the folder you want to appear.